# How can I switch activities when clicking a date using a DatePicker in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I new to Android Studio, and would like to know how to switch to another activity after clicking a date using a DatePicker? Or, at the very least, make text appear on the screen after clicking a date. I have read the documentation for DatePicker and looked at some tutorials and for some reason, I am still lost on this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

(Edit)
Alright, so I did some more work and found out I was missing an OnClickListener. The problem now is the text for date only changes if I click on the border of the DatePicker and not the actual date.

Currently, my code is as follows:

activity.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.wes19_000.working_on_it.MainMenu">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dateText"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="162dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="461dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainMenu.java

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TextView dateText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
        datePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        dateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();
        String date = (month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        dateText.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatePicker` supports a listener, but you need to initialize the date picker in order to use the listener.

```
datePicker.init(2000,6,15, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){...});
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem.